# Single field in select statement returning two columns

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

So I'm running a query like so:

> select col1 from table_name

and it's returning me two columns:

> Server Name | col1

I've not run into this before.  I'm sure it's surprisingly simple, but it's surprisingly hard to search for online.  Any way I can JUST get col1 back?

Comment: Please post your actual SQL. (What you've posted wouldn't return what you're indicating it does, and `table` is a reserved word and couldn't be used as you've used it, so it can't be the real query.) Try calling your mechanic and asking "I have a problem with my car. It's making a funny sound just like the one that drove by my house a few minutes ago. What's wrong and how much to fix it?"

Comment: I assure you, that's the actual query (all I've done is change column names from the real ones to col1 and table name to table).  This is why I'm asking!

Comment: @KenWhite actually it did, thanks - Sebastian worked it out below, and it **does** return an additional column.  Connected to a single server and it's all fixed.

Comment: Yep, I see that. :-) I removed my last comment.

Answer (score 6):

In SSMS you can select to run a query against multiple servers/databases at once. When you do that each result has an additional column added with the server name. That is most likely what is going on here. Close the query window, open a new one and make sure you directly connect to the server in question. That should remove that column.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx

Comment: +1. Nice catch. It didn't even occur to me that someone would run a query without using a database first.